# BinaryFormatter with MemoryStream Question

Tags: c#, memorystream, binaryformatter

I am testing BinaryFormatter to see how it will work for me and I have a simple question:

When using it with the string HELLO, and I convert the MemoryStream to an array, it gives me 29 dimensions, with five of them being the actual data towards the end of the dimensions:

```
            BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();

            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();

            byte[] bytes;
            string originalData = "HELLO";

            bf.Serialize(ms, originalData);
            ms.Seek(0, 0);

            bytes = ms.ToArray();
```

returns

```
-       bytes   {Dimensions:[29]}   byte[]
        [0] 0   byte
        [1] 1   byte
        [2] 0   byte
        [3] 0   byte
        [4] 0   byte
        [5] 255 byte
        [6] 255 byte
        [7] 255 byte
        [8] 255 byte
        [9] 1   byte
        [10]    0   byte
        [11]    0   byte
        [12]    0   byte
        [13]    0   byte
        [14]    0   byte
        [15]    0   byte
        [16]    0   byte
        [17]    6   byte
        [18]    1   byte
        [19]    0   byte
        [20]    0   byte
        [21]    0   byte
        [22]    5   byte
        [23]    72  byte
        [24]    69  byte
        [25]    76  byte
        [26]    76  byte
        [27]    79  byte
        [28]    11  byte
```

Is there a way to only return the data encoded as bytes without all the extraneous information?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

All of that extraneous information tells the other BinaryFormatter (that will deserialize the object) what *type* of object is being deserialized (in this case, `System.String`).  Depending on the type, it includes other information needed to reconstruct the object (for instance, if it were a `StringBuilder`, the `Capacity` would also be encoded in there.

If all you want to do is stuff a string into a `MemoryStream` buffer:

```
        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
        using (TextWriter writer = new StreamWriter(ms))
        {
            writer.Write("HELLO");
            writer.Flush();

            byte[] bytes = ms.ToArray();
        }
```

Comment: Note: the `StreamWriter` constructor internally creates an instance of `UTF8Encoding` to do the actual conversion to bytes. If all you need is an array of bytes corresponding to a string, then `MemoryStream` and `TextWriter` are not actually the solution - they're just a coincidental way of implicitly creating the class that provides the solution. Just use `Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes` directly - or use the correct encoding class for the character encoding you require (UTF-8 is a good default choice).

Answer (score 2):

For a simple string, use a BinaryWriter. The overhead will be reduced to a small length prefix.

BinaryFormatter is intended for serializing (complex) object clusters and needs some auxiliary data structures to do that.

Answer (score 2):

It depends what you actually want. You can get a UTF8 byte array from a string with Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes.

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't strip away all that "extraneous" information.  The deserializer needs it on the other end when you want to reconstitute the object from the serialized data.

Answer (score 2):

Are you just trying to convert the string to a byte array?  If that is your goal, you can do something more like:

```
byte[] bits = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("HELLO");
```